# Batch rename files regular expression on Mac

Tags: regex, macos

I'm trying to batch rename PDF files to remove all characters from right to left until a numeric character is reached on Mac OS.

For example:

10002ASmith.pdf > 10002.pdf

1023AJones.pdf > 1023.pdf

The numeric length in the beginning of the files is variable so I figure would be best to have regex rename from right to left until a number is reached.

I know Mac Yosemite comes with batch rename capabilities but didn't see a regex rename option. Is it easy to do this in terminal and if so how, or is there a free program I can use to use a regular expression?

I suppose I just need to know what the actual regular expression would be since I'm far from experienced in regex.

Thank you for help in advance!

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `find` with `sed`:

```
cd to /path/of/pdfs

while IFS= read -rd '' line; do
   echo mv "$line" $(sed 's~\./[a-zA-Z]*\([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]\).*\(\.pdf\)$~\1\2~' <<< "$line")
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]\{1,\}\.pdf$' -print0)
```

**Remove** `echo` after you verify it is working.

Comment: Uh, you use `-print0` predicate in `find` but don't handle it afterwards, so the command doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected. But are you sure that it is `IFS=` specifically? I tried `read` without `IFS=` but with the `-d ''` option and it did work.

Comment: Could you provide a case where `IFS=` is needed? I ran the following command, having `.pdf` files with spaces in the directory: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -print0 | while read -d '' line; do echo $line; done` and it prints whole filenames on separate lines. So wouldn't appropriate quoting be sufficient?

Comment: Thank you for this solution @anubhava - this worked perfectly and I appreciate the fast response!

Comment: @anubhava, one last question - is it possible to strip any preceeding letters that appear? Ex: HD100ASmith.pdf > 100.pdf? Thank you!

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for the reply - unfortunately with the amount of files to keep unique I have to rename to keep all numbers and only the 1st letter to the right like so: 43ASmith.pdf > 43A.pdf or HD417ALin > 417A.pdf  -- Thank you again and I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @anubhava This is perfect! Thank you so much for your kind help, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to do so.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I'm looking at your revisions to understand how I could also rename files to only remove author last name (except first letter after number) and keep everything else: 

HD101AKailash.pdf > HD101A.pdf or
L141VShibata.pdf > L141V.pdf or
13ASellers.pdf > 13A.pdf

This will be the last change required - many thanks again for your help..

Comment: Try changing `sed` to `sed 's~\./\([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]\).*\(\.pdf\)$~\1\2~'` but please don't change requirements using long comments session. If you have a new requirement you can create a new question by linking to this answer.

Answer (score 8):

[NameChanger](https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/) sounds like a good fit for this purpose - it's free, and will preview the proposed batch regex rename before applying it.

In the example below, I've used the regex `^(\d+).*`, and replaced with `$1.pdf`.

[image: regex rename]

Answer (score 5):

I would propose to do it in shell, using `find` and `sed`, but in a simpler fashion that @anubhava proposed. However, note that it won't work when files have whitespace in them. Version that handles whitespace would be somewhat more complicated.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' | while read filename; do newfilename=`echo $filename | sed '/[0-9]/s/[^0-9]*\.pdf/.pdf/'`; echo mv $filename $newfilename; done
```

Explanation:

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf'` — print all `.pdf` files in the current directory;
- `while read filename; do` + `done` — loop that will operate on every line from the `find` results (line being saved in `filename` variable);
- `/[0-9]/s/[^0-9]*\.pdf/.pdf/` — that's the "business" part. It consists of the regex address `/[0-9]/` (which means "apply the following command only on filenames that contain a digit") and `s` command;
- the `s` expression itself, `s/[^0-9]*\.pdf$/.pdf/`, means "find as much non-digit characters as possible, followed by `.pdf` and the end of the name, and change it to `.pdf`";
- command substitution lets us create `newfilename` contents.

The pipeline will echo the proposed commands to the terminal. If you're happy with the result, you can rerun it with piping the output to the shell command, for example

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' | while read filename; do newfilename=`echo $filename | sed '/[0-9]/s/[^0-9]*\.pdf/.pdf/'`; echo mv $filename $newfilename; done | bash
```

if you use `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @werkritter!

Comment: Best solution! Great job! I've never used an /s/ expression but in a nutshell, it says replace the next term (between the slashes) with the final term (between the slashes). In my case I had 100s of files with Some Name follwed by the same text to be removed: SomeName_same_text.jpg so I used /s/_same_text.jpg/.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) which supports renaming files in bulk using regular expressions..

```
$ renamer --find '/(\d+).*/' --replace '$1' --path-element name --dry-run *

Dry run

✔︎ 10002ASmith.pdf → 10002.pdf
✔︎ 10230CJones.pdf → 10230.pdf

Rename complete: 2 of 2 files renamed.
```